# Laravel 5 Route::DELETE for remove from join table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 for my REST API application. I need to know, what is the proper way of keeping Route rules to remove data from join table. At the moment I am making it like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function(){
    ...
    Route::delete('/customers/{customerid}', 'CustomerController@destroy');
    ...
    Route::delete('/customers/{customerid}/notes', 'CustomerController@removeCustomerNote');
    ...
}
```

But, If I make it like following, delete 'Note' conflicting with 'Customer' delete.

> Route::delete('/customers/notes/{customerid}', 'CustomerController@destroy');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes match from the top down - so just switch the order if you need the top one to take precedence

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function(){
  ...
  Route::delete('/customers/{customerid}/notes', 'CustomerController@removeCustomerNote');
  ...
  Route::delete('/customers/{customerid}', 'CustomerController@destroy');
  ...
}
```

For deleting a join table, you can do nested resources:

```
Route::delete('/customers/{customerid}/notes/{noteId}', 'CustomerController@removeCustomerNote');
```